# Sharing a Vagrant box

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, homestead, vagrantfile

I have a new developer coming to work with me soon, and I'd like to make it as simple as possible for them to get a development environment set up.

I'm currently using a Vagrant (Laravel Homestead) box with about 15 domains set up, each with different configurations (different PHP versions etc), and I'd like to just share the existing box with them if possible.

Is it as simple setting up a repository with the VagrantFile, getting them to clone it and provision the box, or are there more steps involved?

Also, I've had to edit the MySQL configuration on the box, is there any way I can include these updates in what I share with them, or will they just need to reconfigure their own version manually?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to share the Homestead environment is to use the `after.sh` file to to perform any customization you may need beyond what Homestead gives you.

You can also copy your `Homestead.yaml` file to `Homestead.yaml.example` for the new coworker to easily copy and paste the sites & any other configuration changes.